# Redirecting a command with parameters to a file

Tags: linux, shell, redirect

I have the following command

```
/home/ec2-user/MyDomain/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 main.asgi:channel_layer
```

I would like to redirect the console output to a file. I tried doing this

```
/home/ec2-user/MyDomain/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 main.asgi:channel_layer >> /var/log/access.log
```

but that does not work. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong. Ultimately I would like to start that as a background process using & and log the output to a file

Comment: The output your seeing is probably stderr (filedescriptor 2).Try 2>>/var/log/access.log

Comment: @PSkocik yes that worked. And to start it in the background simply add & to the proc name ?

Comment: After the whole command, yes.

Comment: @PSkocik that worked can you put that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error messages that aren't part of a program's primary output should and usually do go to filedescriptor `2` (`stderr`). To redirect an output filedescriptor `N` to a file, you need `N>the_file` (or `N>>the_file`) (i.e., `2>>the_file` to redirect filedescriptor 2`).

When you omit the number, `1` (`stdout`) is implied for output redirections to a file and `0` for input redirections from a file.

(You can also do descriptor to descriptor redirections (`SrcFd>&TargetFd`) and/or closes (`Fd>&-`) and there the direction of the arrow doesn't matter.)

Comment: so how do I tell it to write 2 and everything else to the file

Comment: @MistyD `2>>the_file >&2` is one way to make both stdout and stderr go to `the_file` in append mode.